# Reorganization of a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, r

I have a multidimensional array that I would like to reorganize.

The array in question contains data on 100 traded commodities, traded bilaterally between 180 countries, over 10 years. This dataset is in the form of a multidimensional array (m1), and is structured as follows `[year, donor country, recipient country, commodity]`. So for instance `m1[8,178,54,93]` contains a value which corresponds to the amount of commodity 93 that went from country 178 (USA in this case) to country 54 (China in this case) in year 8.

Although this array is structured as `[year, donor country, recipient country, commodity]`, I would like to have it structured as `[commodity, donor country, recipient country, year]` to be consistent with other similarly structured arrays.

What is the best way to go about this, short of using a series of nested for-loops? I'm imagining something akin to a transpose, which would work for a 2D array, however I haven't found something that would work for my particular problem.

Comment: `help("aperm")`, which is linked in `help("t")`.

Comment: Thank you! This appears to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Roland suggested, `aperm` is indeed the solution to the issue I was having.